# synology setup wordpress with multisite and multi domain

Tags: wordpress, multisite, synology

Thanks so much, I have studied how to set it up for long but still not concrete answer.

May I know how I can setup wordpress with multi site and multi domain in synology?

for example, I am setting up a site of 2 different domains but hosting with 2 different subdirectory of wordpress

www.abc.com -> 192.168.1.100/wordpress1

www.def.com -> 192.168.1.100/wordpress2

how can I make such configurations to serve the purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Web Services -> Enable Web Station -> Click Virtual Host -> In the sub-folder enter the name of the folder you use for 'wordpress1' -> In Hostname type your domain name -> Protocol is HTTP -> Port 80.
Then repeat the steps but change 'wordpress1' to the folder name of your second wordpress installation 'wordpress2' -> enter the second domain name.

Repeat for multiple wordpress installations.

*Also make sure your registrar points to the IP address of your Synology NAS and you should be good to go.